# What noun or adjective describes a message/song/poem that is mournful, but intense?

Tags: single-word-requests, meaning, synonyms

I have a word on the tip of my tongue, but I’m not sure what it is. I’ve checked synonyms of words to see if something matched what I was thinking, but I can’t figure it out. I used Google’s generic thesaurus and “One Word” thesaurus.

A term for a message, song or poem that is sad but intense. Like a psalm or lament(as a noun) but without the connotation of numbness or lack of action. Something more desperate, almost soulful. Wrenching, yearning, woeful. Like a word to describe a dialogue reaction to deep injustice. I swear there is a word that captures this accurately, but I can’t think what it is.

A sample sentence would be something like: “After thinking about [some type of injustice], John let out a *blank(as a noun)*” or “After thinking about [some type of injustice] John released a *blank(as an adjective)* song(or exclamation)” or perhaps phrased differently. Sorry if this is a bit confusing, but that’s why I need help defining it!

Comment: *bare one’s soul* comes to mind.

Answer (score 1):

In literature there is the term ***elegy*** (noun) or ***elegiac*** (adjective):

> a sad poem or song : a poem or song that expresses sorrow for someone who is dead ([M-W](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/elegy))

Yet it can be used by extension to describe 'woeful' situations without someone having died:

> ***elegiac***: wistfully mournful.
>
> - She watched repeat serials, fixed on their moody and elegiac characterization.([OxfordL](https://www.google.com/search?q=elegy%20meaning&sxsrf=AOaemvLg8drAncvF4how16bIc186OWhdhA%3A1634713883584&ei=G8FvYa2TI4G3kwWSqpeYCg&oq=elegy%20meaning&gs_lcp=Cgdnd3Mtd2l6EAEYATIHCAAQsQMQQzIICAAQgAQQsQMyBQgAEIAEMgUIABCABDIFCC4QgAQyBQgAEIAEMgUIABCABDIFCAAQgAQyBQgAEIAEMgUIABCABDoECCMQJzoFCAAQkQI6BAgAEEM6CwgAEIAEELEDEIMBOg4ILhCABBCxAxDHARDRAzoICC4QgAQQsQM6BAguEEM6BwguELEDEEM6CwgAEIAEELEDEMkDOgUIABCSA0oECEEYAFDy0CJYrdgiYJflImgAcAJ4AIABpAGIAaIFkgEDMC41mAEAoAEBwAEB&sclient=gws-wiz#dobs=elegiac))

Edit: After your comment I thought of the adjective ***[inconsolable](https://www.google.com/search?q=inconsolable%20meaning&sxsrf=AOaemvJMSv04U0Dcp1Lrti-7ikqMm_982g%3A1634715617105&ei=4cdvYa7EBciC9u8P6JGEwAU&ved=0ahUKEwjuuKmdvtjzAhVIgf0HHegIAVgQ4dUDCA4&uact=5&oq=inconsolable%20meaning&gs_lcp=Cgdnd3Mtd2l6EAMyDQgAEIAEELEDEEYQ-QEyBggAEAcQHjIGCAAQBxAeMgUIABCABDIGCAAQBxAeMgYIABAHEB4yBQgAEIAEMgYIABAHEB4yBggAEAcQHjIFCAAQgAQ6BwgAEEcQsAM6BwgAELADEEM6CgguEMgDELADEEM6DQguEMgDELADEEMQiwM6BwgAEIAEEAo6BAgAEA06CwgAEAcQHhBGEPkBSgUIOBIBMUoECEEYAFDbsThY6sY4YMfJOGgCcAJ4AIABiQGIAfIKkgEDNC45mAEAoAEByAEOuAECwAEB&sclient=gws-wiz)*** which has some dynamic to it since whatever the person does, they cannot be consoled.

***Harrowing*** is more extreme:

> extremely upsetting because connected with suffering:
>
> - a harrowing story ([Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/harrowing))

Comment: I appreciate your response, but it’s not the word I’m looking for. I actually already use the word mournful in the title for my question. Mournful is good, with the connotation of sadness, but it lacks the desperation that I feel is essential to the word I’m thinking of. Elegy is also good, and another one that appeared in the thesaurus when I originally searched for synonyms, but I think it has the same problem as mournful. I think elegy and mournful are too calm, too tame. I need a word with more intensity. Imagine the difference between a tragic symphonic piece, and a sorrowful piano solo.

Comment: Why not use 'tragic'? Although it seems to strong for an injustice...

Comment: tragic is pretty strong, but it seems to imply an accident, or something preventable. It’s not what I’m looking for.

Comment: Harrowing is much closer to the emotion. Not exactly what I’m looking for but much closer.

Comment: Then think of [_**agonizing**_](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/agonizing) or [_**(heart)wrenching**_](https://www.merriam-webster.com/thesaurus/wrenching). "Wrench" means _a forceful rotating or pulling motion for the purpose of dislodging something_ so the metaphor is quite dynamic.

Comment: Heartwrenching is good . That’s one of the synonyms I had considered. That’s pretty close but not exactly what I’m looking for. +1 for heartwrenching

Answer (score 1):

For something more intense than *mournful*, perhaps:

> After thinking about [some type of injustice] John moved those present
> with a **heartrending**  song.

**heartrending** (adj.)

> Causing great sadness or distress. [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/heart-rending?locale=en)

> Causing intense sorrow or emotional anguish; evoking deep compassion;
> deeply distressing or moving.  OED

> Heartbreaking [m-w](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/heartrending)

Comment: heartrending is quite good. It’s not exactly what I’m thinking of but it’s the closest to capturing what I’m trying to say so far. +1 from me